# What is the client connection limit in heroku redis (premium 2)

Tags: heroku, redis

According to their [site](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis), it says connection limit is 200 (premium 2), does that mean that only 200 clients can use my redis db at a time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means your app can open 200 connections to Redis at one time - a client is not == a user to your site. It's typically a process such as `web` defined in your `Procfile` - the more processes you run the more connections you will need.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. Pardon me to bug you one more time. I have a website that uses heroku Redis, does this mean that only 200 people can use my website at a time?

Comment: no, as I said above - a connection is not a user to your site, it's the number of processes you're running (dyno's, web processes etc)